# Python requests for v3 Strava API - Forbidden 403

Tags: python, api, python-requests, strava

Some time ago I did simple app using Strava API, but from the last week it stopped working due to the python request that shows 403 forbidden with information:

"403 Forbidden.
Stravaâs services are currently suspended in Russia and Belarus."

I'm not based in Russia or Belarus and when I tried to type the request directly to the browser it worked correctly. Do you know some solutions to solve this issue?

Comment: maybe you have to add header `Accept-Language` like `Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3`. You may also copy all headers from browser to code and see if it works - and later you can start removing headers until you get headers which you really need.

Comment: @furas thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't help. I copied all the headers from my browser to the to the requests query and I still have the same response =\ (in browser it works normally with the same headers)

Comment: so maybe it needs to use session and first get main page to get fresh cookies and later get data from API. This is how real human behaves. And browser usually have get fresh cookies. Eventually try to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser. Maybe page needs also to run some JavaScript.

Comment: you could create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we could copy and run it.

Comment: did you solve your problem?? I have the same problem using the API with JS. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't solved it yet. I tried with the session, but it didn't work =/